# LiveValidation - Has anyone got it working with multiple select?

Tags: php, html, client-side-validation, livevalidation

I'm working on a website in which I'm using both server-side (PHP) and client-side (LiveValidation - http://www.livevalidation.com/) validation. I've got LiveValidation working with every input field *except* multiple select boxes. Here's a general idea of what the code looks like (I replaced the variable names with generic names):

```
<select name="array[]" id="array" multiple>
<option value="Val1" <?php if( @in_array( 'Val1', @$_POST['array'] ) ) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>Val1</option>
<option value="Val2" <?php if( @in_array( 'Val2', @$_POST['array'] ) ) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>Val2</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
var arr = new LiveValidation('array', { validMessage: ' ', wait: 500});
arr.add( Validate.Presence, { failureMessage: ' ' } );
arr.add( Validate.Exclusion, { within: [ "" ], failureMessage: ' ' } );
</script>
```

Now, I've tried both using `var arr = new LiveValidation('array'` and `var arr = new LiveValidation('array[]'` with no change in functionality (I'm pretty sure that LiveValidation uses id and not name, anyways). Anyone have any idea why it won't work?

Also, if anything in the code seems really off, please feel free to let me know, seeing as I'm pretty new to web development. I take constructive criticism pretty well. :)

Answer (score 0):

what is `value"Val1"` ???

it should be

```
<option value="Val1" <?php if( @in_array( 'Val1', @$_POST['array'] ) ) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>Val1</option>
```

Comment: Oops, that's the way it is in the code. I just made an error while re-writing the code in the browser. My bad! :)